# Not able to debug Azure Logic App workflow using Visual Studio Code

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-single-tenant-workflows-visual-studio-code) tutorial.

I am now able to create the workflow in Visual Studio Code, and also see that in the designer.

[image: Request Response logic app in Visual Studio Code]

But further to this, I am not able to see the url as [mentioned here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-single-tenant-workflows-visual-studio-code#run-test-and-debug-locally) after clicking the overview.

[image: Overview of Azure Logic App Workflow.json file in Visual Studio Code context menu]

I get this message

`Workflow run history could not be loaded. Error: 'Could not establish connection to the host. Run your function project to view the run history. Failed to fetch.'`

[image: Overview of Azure Logic App Workflow.json file in Visual Studio Code]

What am I missing?

[I ensured Azurite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-single-tenant-workflows-visual-studio-code#storage-requirements) is running.

[image: Azurite is running]

[NGrok](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-single-tenant-workflows-visual-studio-code#set-up-call-forwarding-using-ngrok) is also configured.

[image: NGrok is configured]

And my local.settings.json file looks as follows.

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_V2_COMPATIBILITY_MODE": "true",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "WORKFLOWS_TENANT_ID": "d5y4kk56-f47h-df6h-2g7k-sd4fk8f5j5zd",
    "WORKFLOWS_SUBSCRIPTION_ID": "876af6yz-6xxx-1234-2nh7-xxx234gygrkls",
    "WORKFLOWS_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME": "vivek-logic-app-trial-rg",
    "WORKFLOWS_LOCATION_NAME": "centralindia",
    "WORKFLOWS_MANAGEMENT_BASE_URI": "https://management.azure.com/",
    "Workflows.WebhookRedirectHostUri": "http://e91c-115-96-216-18.ngrok.io"
  }
}
```

Not only that, when I press F5, I get the following error, not clear to me what it says.

`Error message: correlationId='683df22d-5928-4149-97cc-2ee3116aa6d0', operationName='SubscriptionExtensions.ToCachedSubscription', message='Resource provider namespace is empty for subscription 'myedgeenvironment', properties '{"tenantId":"myedgeenvironment-tenantId","registeredFeatures":[]}'.', exception='<null>', organizationId='',  activityVector='IN.02', additionalProperties='', extensionVersion='1.0.0.0', siteName='UNDEFINED_SITE_NAME', slotName='', activityId='683df22d-5928-4149-97cc-2ee3116aa6d0'.`

[image: Not able to debug Azure Logic Apps in Visual Studio Code]

Raised on [github Azure-Functions](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/2104) as well.

**Update**

[image: Global.json and dotnet list sdks]

**Udate 2**

I now get this

[image]

Comment: Hello @VivekDev, Could you please let us know are you using  .net3x current version which available in your local instead of .net5 version in global.json file as its not supported to 5x versions . By running the command (dotnet --list-sdks) in your local cmd.

Comment: Hi @AjayKumarGhose-MT, updated the question. Please see.

Comment: Thank you. from the given [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-single-tenant-workflows-visual-studio-code#enable-built-in-connector-authoring) So far i have tried with convert to Nuget based logic-app project and added my current .net3x version in global.json as well , After run i can able to get the URI . Could you please try to add and run again (open the shortcut menu, and select **Convert to Nuget-based Logic App project**.) Here is the screenshot : [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2E2lE.png

Comment: Yes, Thanks @Liam, its obfuscated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for the update @[VivekDev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1977871/vivekdev) , I Finally figured out the problem and was able to debug the logic app in VS CODE after a long time.
Here are the steps that i followed:

1. **Created logic app**
   [image]

2.**Added `global.json` file according to my sdk version in my root folder**

[image]

3. **Then Convert to Nuget-based Logic App project as followed .**

[image]

4. **Here is localsettings.json file sample code** you can try with the following code according to your credential.

   ```
   "IsEncrypted": false,
      "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
        "WORKFLOWS_TENANT_ID": "",
        "WORKFLOWS_SUBSCRIPTION_ID": "",
        "WORKFLOWS_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME": "xxxxxx",
        "WORKFLOWS_LOCATION_NAME": "westus2",
        "WORKFLOWS_MANAGEMENT_BASE_URI": "https://management.azure.com/"
   ```

   [image]

5. **installed [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/download) and authorized using my authentication token and then Connect to the `port 7071`  by running cmd `ngrok http 7071` .**

[image]

Then run the logic app and meanwhile go to **workflow.json overview tab**  and then you will **get url** ,(may be you will get the same error at that time in your terminal) Copy and browse that same url in your browser then check in vs code that logic app run successfully here are the below screenshots for reference .

[image]

[image]

Finally here is my successfully running logic app :
Created workflow :
[image]

**Successfully running workflow**

[image]

**REFERENCE**:- [MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-single-tenant-workflows-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Hi @AjayKumarGhose-MT, I flow the steps you have provided, after doing all this steps, I'm getting new error: (Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.) (Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.)

Can you please suggest way out.. Thanks,

Comment: Hello @ *Deepak Shaw*, Could you please raise a new question with the steps and the error details that you have tried ,so that we can assist you better. Thank you!!